# Initiation issue in tensorflow library

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I got to install 'tensorflow' and 'keras' libraries but when I try to use them I got this error message:

```
> library(tensorflow)
> tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
Error in system2(python, stdout = TRUE, args = c("-c", shQuote("import sys; import platform; sys.stdout.write(platform.architecture()[0])"))) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.8\python.exe -c "import sys; import platform; sys.stdout.write(platform.architecture()[0])"'
```

I assume that I need to change something in the SYSTEM path but what?

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow` which was, as I recall, a two step process, that you've probably done right, but given your output, hard to say.

Comment: In 'R' I installed 'install.package(tensorflow)' and it does not give an error when I lunch it by 'library(tensorflow)'. THe error appear when I try to use functions from ir

Comment: There used to be a `next step`, as install.packages essentially installed an installer, that was run once `install_tensorflow()` after call to `library(tensorflow)`, check out the github readme, though it may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like reticulate found the Python 2 version that was bundled with your ArcGis installation. Tensorflow is not compatible with python 2.

If you want to R/reticulate to configure a compatible python environment, you can run this:

```
reticulate::install_miniconda()
keras::install_keras()
```

Comment: Thanks, it is certainly an issue. however I can not go aroud it by 'install_miniconda()'
I got this
> reticulate::install_miniconda()
* Downloading "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86.exe" ...
trying URL 'https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86.exe'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 57981080 bytes (55.3 MB)
downloaded 55.3 MB

* Installing Miniconda -- please wait a moment ...
Error: Miniconda installation failed [unknown reason]

Comment: Can you please file an issue on github, that sounds like a bug.